# Замена элементов массива PHP

Tags: php, массивы

Добрый день.
У меня есть два массива. Покажу их куски, выведенные через print_r(), для наглядности:
Первый - $pArr

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [c99ac205-72b5-4945-8043-ed69983d9333] => Пусковой ток аккумулятора
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [786f5089-24ab-41b2-80f2-e895bb3c9f55] => Индекс скорости автошины
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [492cccf6-cee5-4650-8459-cecad0fa2ea3] => Модель (автошины, автодиска, аккумулятора)
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [2f1880c0-9d29-4eed-8460-54daa2839f08] => Емкость аккумулятора
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [3f582fa2-7638-4c53-868c-372f5a7e3da4] => Диаметр автодиска
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [39cb3450-9fad-11e0-8b12-001cf0c7ea0e] => Размер
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [39cb3454-9fad-11e0-8b12-001cf0c7ea0e] => Производство
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [fbf5bbb1-4311-4ed0-8d8d-4839efe0184b] => Размер автошины - диаметр
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [2f38bd0b-d9a2-4577-920f-8c50c9f986b2] => Размер автошины - ширина
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [f5928459-6b0a-4e65-94eb-73e5a94605c3] => Назначение автошины
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [2e7798f8-8acb-446e-9a36-35a23f721e76] => Производитель
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [d7d1d16f-6c6f-41ee-a10a-920d395272f9] => Индекс нагрузки на ось автошины
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [4300d693-d759-471c-a3b0-8dd000451ea5] => Размер автошины - профиль
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [55558942-fe60-4325-ab8b-a32371194966] => Ширина автодиска
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [8eec56b2-5c47-4e3a-b638-c4ffe9849f7e] => Вылет автодиска
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [03f5629f-94fa-43db-b65a-32ca5ed0b72a] => Крепеж автодиска
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [7923f7b3-de8e-4dc6-bd22-3b93944e7f53] => Тип протектора автошины
        )
...
```

Второй массив - $gArr

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Ид] => f4e9dd2f-ee11-11e6-93ba-ce730bee09f3
            [Наименование] => 295/80/22.5 Ellerbrock DE2M (UD2L) R (каркас Michelin) 
            [БазоваяЕдиница] => шт.
            [Группы] => Array
                (
                    [Ид] => 9930ec10-edea-11e6-afa5-1c6f65c3c754
                )

            [Картинка] => import_files/f4/f4e9dd2f-ee11-11e6-93ba-ce730bee09f3_1cac6b30-ef5a-11e6-93ba-ce730bee09f3.jpeg
            [ЗначенияСвойств] => Array
                (
                    [ЗначенияСвойства] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [Ид] => c99ac205-72b5-4945-8043-ed69983d9333
                                    [Значение] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [Ид] => 786f5089-24ab-41b2-80f2-e895bb3c9f55
                                    [Значение] => db3d1e6a-1c5d-11df-9276-001517645230
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [Ид] => 492cccf6-cee5-4650-8459-cecad0fa2ea3
                                    [Значение] => 9930ec12-edea-11e6-afa5-1c6f65c3c754
                                )

                            [3] => Array
                                (
                                    [Ид] => 2f1880c0-9d29-4eed-8460-54daa2839f08
                                    [Значение] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                            [4] => Array
                                (
                                    [Ид] => 3f582fa2-7638-4c53-868c-372f5a7e3da4
                                    [Значение] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                            [5] => Array
                                (
                                    [Ид] => 39cb3450-9fad-11e0-8b12-001cf0c7ea0e
                                    [Значение] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                            [6] => Array
                                (
                                    [Ид] => 39cb3454-9fad-11e0-8b12-001cf0c7ea0e
                                    [Значение] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                            [7] => Array
                                (
                                    [Ид] => fbf5bbb1-4311-4ed0-8d8d-4839efe0184b
                                    [Значение] => 1dabdc5e-42de-11df-a7bb-0015172306b5
                                )

                            [8] => Array
                                (
                                    [Ид] => 2f38bd0b-d9a2-4577-920f-8c50c9f986b2
                                    [Значение] => 1dabdbfe-42de-11df-a7bb-0015172306b5
                                )

                            [9] => Array
                                (
                                    [Ид] => f5928459-6b0a-4e65-94eb-73e5a94605c3
                                    [Значение] => 342c1d6e-1cd0-11e6-a8f5-e069953c5ea7
                                )

                            [10] => Array
                                (
                                    [Ид] => c79b6c51-35e6-4f56-9916-5be7e4d3fdc2
                                    [Значение] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                            [11] => Array
                                (
                                    [Ид] => 2e7798f8-8acb-446e-9a36-35a23f721e76
                                    [Значение] => 9930ec11-edea-11e6-afa5-1c6f65c3c754
                                )

                            [12] => Array
                                (
                                    [Ид] => d7d1d16f-6c6f-41ee-a10a-920d395272f9
                                    [Значение] => 342c1d6f-1cd0-11e6-a8f5-e069953c5ea7
                                )

                            [13] => Array
                                (
                                    [Ид] => 3e9a8dd0-e415-41af-a1d3-4fd8eb5ea721
                                    [Значение] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                            [14] => Array
                                (
                                    [Ид] => 4300d693-d759-471c-a3b0-8dd000451ea5
                                    [Значение] => 365093a2-42de-11df-a7bb-0015172306b5
                                )

                            [15] => Array
                                (
                                    [Ид] => dd611e71-fac8-4790-a3c9-041196bfeb17
                                    [Значение] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                            [16] => Array
                                (
                                    [Ид] => b06468a6-bc02-4130-a850-101680a6a117
                                    [Значение] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                            [17] => Array
                                (
                                    [Ид] => 55558942-fe60-4325-ab8b-a32371194966
                                    [Значение] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                            [18] => Array
                                (
                                    [Ид] => 8eec56b2-5c47-4e3a-b638-c4ffe9849f7e
                                    [Значение] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                            [19] => Array
                                (
                                    [Ид] => 03f5629f-94fa-43db-b65a-32ca5ed0b72a
                                    [Значение] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                            [20] => Array
                                (
                                    [Ид] => 7923f7b3-de8e-4dc6-bd22-3b93944e7f53
                                    [Значение] => 483b960c-d3c2-4535-806e-b1166653abb2
                                )

                        )

                )
...
```

А вот, как я делаю замену:

```
$itemsArr = array_replace_recursive($gArr, $pArr);
print_r($itemsArr);
```

array_replace_recursive — рекурсивно заменяет элементы первого массива элементами переданных массивов. Но у меня ни чего не происходит. В чём ошибка?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В массиве $pArr `2e7798f8-8acb-446e-9a36-35a23f721e76` - это ключ массива, а в $gArr `2e7798f8-8acb-446e-9a36-35a23f721e76` - это значения для ключа "Ид". array_replace_recursive заменяет значения исходного массива на соответствующие по **ключам** значения.
Делайте через `foreach` с поиском и заменой значений "Ид" в массиве $pArr.

Comment: Получается, что array_replace не подходит. Дело в том, что данная функция производит замену при найденных совпадения, либо добавляет новые при отсутствии совпадений. А мне нужна только замена. Других подобных функций не нашёл. Как тогда сделать замену?